# Unable to expand mat row

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to display a table and expand the rows when they are clicked to show some additional information.

I have the following HTML / TS displaying the table without issue, but when I add the connect code - the rows don't react on click and rows is printed as "[]" in the console..

Html:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let apptestlist"> {{apptestlist.Name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="AppCount">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Application Count </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let apptestlist"> {{apptestlist.Apps.length}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let apptestlist"> 
        The symbol for {{apptestlist.Name}} is Banana
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
            matRipple 
            class="element-row" 
            [class.expanded]="expandedElement == row"
            (click)="expandedElement === row? expandedElement = null : expandedElement = row"></mat-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']; when: isExpansionDetailRow"
            [@detailExpand]="row.element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
            style="overflow: hidden"> 
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppTestListService } from '../services/app-test-list-service'
import { AppTestList } from '../models/AppTestList';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-application-test-lists',
  templateUrl: './application-test-lists.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application-test-lists.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', visibility: 'hidden' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*', visibility: 'visible' })),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
})

export class ApplicationTestListsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private appTestListService: AppTestListService) { }

  dataSource = new AppTestListDataSource(this.appTestListService);
  displayedColumns = ['Name', 'AppCount'];
  appTestLists: AppTestList[];
  loading = true;
  isExpansionDetailRow = (i: number, row: Object) => row.hasOwnProperty('detailRow');
  expandedElement: any;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

export class AppTestListDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private appTestListService: AppTestListService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<AppTestList[]> {
    return this.appTestListService.list();
  }
  disconnect() {}
}
```

This renders nicely how I want it:

[image]

I want to be able to expand the rows and display some additional information e.g

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let apptestlist"> 
    The symbol for {{apptestlist.Name}} is Banana
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

However it's not working..

I've changed my connect method to the following but it appears to return before any changes have happened:

```
  connect(): Observable<AppTestList[]> {
    const rows = [];
    let data = this.appTestListService.list();
    data.forEach(element => rows.push(element, { detailRow: true, element }));
    console.log(rows);
    return of(rows);
  }
```

list():

```
  public list(): Observable<AppTestList[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<AppTestList[]>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}`);
  }
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `AppTestListService.list()`?

Comment: I'll update it shortly - .list() returns an observable<apptestlist> that does a http get to a remote endpoint..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `AppTestListService.list()` returns an `Observable` with or without the records initially, it is being assigned to your `data` variable and your `forEach`, `console.log` and `return of(rows)` completes before your `.get` is finished retrieving the records.

You will need to wrap that part in a subscribe to ensure that it happens when you know you have the data from the `.get`

**Also Note:**

> `{{apptestlist.Name}}` does not mean anything to your detail row, you may want `{{apptestlist.element.Name}}` instead.

```
connect(): Observable<AppTestList[]> {
       const rows = [];
       this.appTestListService.list().subscribe(val=>{
         val.forEach(element => rows.push(element, { detailRow: true, element }));
       })
       return of(rows);
     }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-golnkq?embed=1&file=app/table-basic-example.html